# Logic Apps - Converting HTML symbols in plain text

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Fairly new to Logic Apps and not familiar with all the functions.

I created a simple Logic App that will check an RSS feed every so often, loops every item it finds, takes only certain data (title, summary and URL link), paste them in an HTML table and then send an email with the outcome. Sounds fairly simple, right?

The problem I'm facing is that the RSS feed contains certain HTML characters such as `&amp;` or `&#39;`, which will then appear in the email I receive. Is it possible to convert these in Logic Apps?

Additionally, I've also noticed that some HTML character are "double encoded??"
Basically if we had to look at `<description>&amp;quot;Quando Romelu si mette in testa una cosa, di solito la ottiene. Ora, si sarebbe messo in testa l&amp;rsquo;Inter.</description>` straight away you'd realise that the first `&amp;` is there for the `quot;` that follows it. So it's kind of expecting that first the `&amp;` is converted in an actual & to then form `&quot;` to be then converted to ", if it makes sense what I'm saying. I don't own the feed, or in any way control it. Wanted to get familiar with Logic Apps so I thought I'd start with some football news processing.

Here's a sample of one item(out of 20) in the RSS feed

```
<item>
  <guid>https://www.fcinternews.it/?action=read&amp;idnotizia=310797</guid>
  <pubDate>Wed, 19 Jun 2019 09:51:40 +0200</pubDate>
  <title>CdS - Il BVB vuole Pinamonti: valutazione schizzata oltre i 20 milioni </title>
  <link>https://www.fcinternews.it/rassegna/cds-il-bvb-vuole-pinamonti-valutazione-schizzata-oltre-i-20-milioni-310797</link>
  <description>Anche il Corriere dello Sport sottolinea la grande fila che si &amp;egrave; messa in attesa di buone nuove dall&amp;#39;Inter per Andrea Pinamonti, protogonista del Mondiale U-20.</description>
  <category>Rassegna</category>
  <enclosure url="https://net-storage.tccstatic.com/storage/fcinternews.it/img_notizie/thumb1/ec/ec620af4eeb01ebebbb662d7947a6700-85495-21a8fcf5fc9c392cfa4303d2753d5db6.jpeg" type="image/jpeg" length="9983"/>
</item>
```

Comment: What action did you use? I tried [List all RSS feed items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/#list-all-rss-feed-items) and check what it response, it doesn't include guid or description.

Comment: So I started with a Recurrence action, followed by List all RSS feed items, then Create HTML table and finally Send an email. I have no issues getting description. The XML node is `<description>` and from within the Logic Apps designer it is listed as summary, but it still worked.

Comment: Thanks for the link. To further answer your question, I want to manipulate the data inside Feed title and Feed summary which are in the [FeedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/#feeditem) object

Comment: I have found it. it's my fault. I check the run history and found actually the HTML table body didn't contains &amp; or &#39 and if you check the [Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkbrS.png) it will have. So i believe logic app already convert it.

Comment: You're right George. It is converting them, even on my end. This is the [raw XML](https://i.imgur.com/9uQT9Ju.jpg) from the feed, here's the [HTML table output](https://i.imgur.com/TvaJyz8.jpg) that I can see on Azure and here's what I receive in my [inbox](https://i.imgur.com/ssACdXa.jpg).

Comment: It is successfully converting `&amp;#39;` into &#39;. It's as if it needs to go over the text again and then convert whatever is left. The issue is clearly the source mind you. I might need to add some Javascript logic to output clean text in my email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the solution to use an Azure function to clean it up [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow)

However, as you are doing something like this I guess you can do replace actions and oh btw single quotation escapes suck. Use a variable to cheat it.

`replace(replace(replace(replace(item()['summary'],'&nbsp;',' '),'&amp;','& '),'&quot;','"'),'&#39;','')`

`replace(replace(replace(replace(item()['title'],'&nbsp;',' '),'&amp;','& '),'&quot;','"'),'&#39;',variables('EscapeSingleQuotation'))`

[image: Flow]

Result

[image: html table]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks AdAstra, looks like this is what I'm after! I considered creating an Azure Function App to do this logic but then I said if I'm creating a Function App then might as well do everything in there because I get to manipulate the data easily with C# and some Nuget package. I like your approach (replace function) and I'm going to give it a try. Perhaps not the cleanest but uses less Azure resources. The only problem with this is that I would need to study the patter of all the HTML characters in the RSS feed and add them one by one in my replace function. Thanks again!

Comment: @bonnu18 No problem, happy to help. I agree that this might not be the best solution but rather a quick and dirty one. I want to create something with the least amount of actions using expressions but you are right in that you will have to go over all cases you have to cover. I guess you could use notepad++ to first create your 'schema to replace' using https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp for at least a few of the special characters.

Comment: this worked for me thanks! Ended up doing a really long on too to cover special letters and other characters `@replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(item()['summary'],'&amp;','&'),'&nbsp;',' '),'&quot;','\"'),'&rsquo;','’'),'&#39;',''''),'&agrave;','à'),'&Agrave;','À'),'&egrave;','è'),'&Egrave;','È'),'&igrave;','ì'),'&Igrave;','Ì'),'&ograve;','ò'),'&Ograve;','Ò'),'&ugrave;','ù'),'&Ugrave;','Ù'),'&eacute;','é'),'&Eacute;','É')`

Comment: I also tried to add a Javascript function and then pass the text as a parameter and have the sanitised text returned, but then it was asking me to add an integration account to the logic apps. I was after the least resourceful solution so I discarded that straight away and added that long replace . Considering that this Logic Apps is intended for non-technical people, it's not always straight forward.

Comment: The integration account is actually just a resource in azure just as any other api connection in this regard. For the online code action it is a container that you don’t have to think more about. To add a integration account to a logic app you would just edit the “workflow settings”. But yeah in this instance I think your solution works fine and otherwise go with a function.

Comment: In my honest opinion, for what I achieved from this logic app (that being a very simple HTML table with no formatting) I could have easily achieved this with C# and it will be ready in just 2 hours tops! Nothing beats custom software development. Logic Apps failed to impress me unfortunately

Comment: In my honest opinion, for what I achieved from this logic app (that being a very simple HTML table with no formatting) I could have easily achieved this with C# and it will be ready in just 2 hours tops! Nothing beats custom software development. Logic Apps failed to impress me unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft have included new connector called - **[Content Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/)**.
This converts HTML contents to plain string.

This is available on Logic Apps, Power Automate, Power Apps. But still on **preview phase.**

[image]