# Write HTML inside HTML Table Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm parsing some JSON into an HTML table in Azure Logic Apps. I want some list elements to be separated into multiline  cell.  Example:
[image]

However, the < and > symbols are being escaped causing this to be interpreted literally in the output:
[image]

Is there any way to escape the escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below replace actions to remove those html escape characters.

```html
replace(replace(variables('string'),'<br>',' '),'<test>', ' ')
```

Here is the sample output when using the above replace action

[image]

- Alternatively, Microsoft have included new connector called -  **[Content Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/)**.This converts HTML contents to plain string.

Here is the sample output :
[image]

- You can also you azure function to remove those [html escape characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow)

Here is the [reference SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663281/logic-apps-converting-html-symbols-in-plain-text)

Comment: The query is not about removing the tags but to apply it.